# Display \n \r correctly in HTML from JSON

Tags: json, gwt, html-encode

I have a String fetched from a Database and send from a backend using Servlet. The servlet constructs the JSON and send it to the client

I use this function to escape the JSON

```
public static String toHTML(String string){
        StringBuffer sb =  new StringBuffer();
                    for(int i=0;i<string.length();i++){
                            char ch=string.charAt(i);
                            switch(ch){
                            case '"':
                                    sb.append("\\\"");
                                    break;
                            case '\\':
                                    sb.append("\\\\");
                                    break;
                            case '\b':
                                    sb.append("\\b");
                                    break;
                            case '\f':
                                    sb.append("\\f");
                                    break;
                            case '\n':
                                    sb.append("\\n");
                                    break;
                            case '\r':
                                    sb.append("\\r");
                                    break;
                            case '\t':
                                    sb.append("\\t");
                                    break;
                            case '/':
                                    sb.append("\\/");
                                    break;
                            default:
                    //Reference: http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.1.0/
                                    if((ch>='\u0000' && ch<='\u001F') || (ch>='\u007F' && ch<='\u009F') || (ch>='\u2000' && ch<='\u20FF')){
                                            String ss=Integer.toHexString(ch);
                                            sb.append("\\u");
                                            for(int k=0;k<4-ss.length();k++){
                                                    sb.append('0');
                                            }
                                            sb.append(ss.toUpperCase());
                                    }
                                    else{
                                            sb.append(ch);
                                    }
                            }
                    }//for
                    return sb.toString();

    }
```

But, once displayed, I see the escaped characters. Example "something \r\n".
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

`\r\n` is obivously nothing a browser can interpret. Replace `\r\n` with `<br>` and you got your line break in HTML. Replace the other tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript function to replace newline chars

```
var nl2br = function(str, is_xhtml) {
    var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br />' : '<br>';
    return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');
}

console.log(nl2br('asdf', false));     // asdf

console.log(nl2br('as\r\ndf', false)); // as<br>
                                       //
                                       // df

console.log(nl2br('as\n\rdf', true));​  // as<br />
                                       //
                                       // df
```